# How do I enable BitLocker only in "clear key" mode?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

I have some laptops that come with a form of BitLocker enabled where the data on the drive is encrypted but there is no key protector set, i.e. there is no dependency on any password, TPM, etc., to decrypt the drive.

It looks like this to `manage-bde`:

```
Volume C: [Windows-SSD]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 951.65 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:       None Found
```

I also use Macrium Reflect to manage my backups. In [certain situations](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW80/BitLocker+Restore+Outcomes), a restored backup may remove BitLocker encryption entirely.

I would like to re-enable BitLocker back in the clear key state after it has been removed e.g. due to a backup restore. How do I do this?

---

If anyone's interested in the *why*, it's half wanting the post-restore state to be actually identical to the original state, and half wanting to make it easier to wipe the drive later without making the backup process more difficult. At this point I'm not quite ready to enable BitLocker "properly".

Comment: If you want the post-restore to be a state identical to that of the original state you need to resume BitLocker protection and use a BitLocker protector like a TPM or password.

Comment: @Ramhound The original state did *not* have full BitLocker activated with a TPM or password. This is the state I want to be in.

Comment: You do understand the current state is not exactly considered to be secure.

Comment: @Ramhound It's no less secure than the state these laptops were in before the backup-restore cycle. And that's the state I want to be in. I explicitly do *not* want an actually encrypted (read: requires TPM/password/etc.) drive, since that makes things like modifying files offline difficult by design.

Comment: So is there a reason you don't disable BitLocker protection if you don't actually want the drive contents encrypted? Technically your BitLocker state, as indicated in your status output, is already in "clear key" mode.

Comment: @Ramhound That status output is *before* the restore operation. *After* the restore operation it becomes `Fully Decrypted` instead. Anyway, this is pointless arguing over information I already included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way to enable this state is "Device Encryption", which is a bit of a subset of BitLocker that is also available on Home editions. This is available under the "Privacy & Security" section of Settings. This appears to only be available on some specific machines, e.g. I can see it on these laptops but not on custom-built desktops.

Enabling this *without* a Microsoft Account appears to encrypt the drive in the same partial state as it comes from the OEM.

---

The steps that follow are from the original answer and work for applying a similar form of encryption via BitLocker, but is not quite identical to the original Device Encryption option (notably, it sets Device Encryption into "Managed by BitLocker" mode). They also require a Pro edition.

It looks like the "clear key" state can be accomplished by first encrypting the drive with a key protector, then removing all key protectors.

```
manage-bde -on C: -used
```

This turns on BitLocker, probably with the default of the TPM. There is a `-Password` option but may require changing a group policy setting to allow it. No matter, we remove the TPM protector in the next step. But first, a reboot is required and then the drive should start encrypting (as shown by `manage-bde -status`).

Make sure the drive has at least stated encrypting (after reboot). Removing the protectors before encryption starts will leave the drive in the fully decrypted state instead.

Next up we remove all protectors:

```
manage-bde -protectors -delete C:
```

And we should now be in an encrypted but clear key state.